# Access to web method parameters in JAX-WS SOAP handler?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, java-7

I've developed a SOAP web service with Java7 and JAX-WS. This is an excerpt of the interface:

```
@WebService(name = "MyWebService",
            targetNamespace = "http://www.something.com")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public interface MyWebServiceInterface
{
   @WebMethod(operationName = "handleMsg",
              action = "handleMsg")
   @Oneway
   void handleMsg(@WebParam(name = "MessageHeader",
                            targetNamespace = "http://www.something.com",
                            header = true,
                            partName = "header") 
                  MessageHeader header,
                  @WebParam(name = "MessageBody",
                            targetNamespace = "http://www.soemthing.com",
                            partName = "body") 
                  MessageType body);
}
```

I've implemented a custom SOAP handler for this web service (it work's fine) to do some additional stuff. In the method `handleFault(..)` I need to access the original `MessageHeader` of the web method (see interface above). How can this be done?

```
public class MyHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>
{
   // ...

   @Override
   public boolean handleFault(final SOAPMessageContext context)
   {
       final Boolean outbound =
          ( Boolean ) context.get( MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY );

       // handle only incoming message which do have a message set
       if ( outbound != null && !outbound.booleanValue() && context.getMessage() != null )
       {
          MessageHeader header = 
             getOriginalHeaderOfFautlyMessage();  // <-- how can this be done?
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SOAPMessage soapMsg = context.getMessage();
SOAPEnvelope soapEnv = soapMsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
SOAPHeader soapHeader = soapEnv.getHeader();
```

Then you will have to extract your header node and unmarshall it.

Comment: Ok, I see. I can then use `soapHeader.getElementsByTagName( .. )` to retrieve individual elements and construct the `MessageHeader` by hand. Is there any way to speed that up and retrieve the fully generated object? Somehow it does it the other way already...

Comment: @MarkusL
Are you using CXF? If so, I think that if your handler is invoked past UNMARSHALL phase then there will be your web method params in List parameters = soapMessage.getContent(List.class);
see http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.cxf/cxf-api/2.7.17/org/apache/cxf/interceptor/DocLiteralInInterceptor.java#DocLiteralInInterceptor

 and http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html

Comment: No, I'm using pure Java with JAX-WS!